# What's the 'Frequent' sort function?

Tags: support, questions, sorting, frequent-tab

What is the function of the ['Frequent'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=frequent) sorting option on the Questions tab?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When many questions are closed as a duplicate of one specific question, that question is a "Frequent" question - that is, it has been asked, in different guises, frequently. In addition, if the question is linked to from another question, it is one of the "Frequently" linked to questions.

In essence the sort is for questions that have been linked to often within the site.

If you hover over the tab, the tooltip is "questions with the most links" - that is, with many  questions linking to it.

Comment: In other words: *Frequently Linked Questions*. Note that that tab was previously called "FAQ" which stood for *Frequently Asked Questions*. This is further not necessarily related to closure as duplicate. It's just that duplicate question closures happen to have a link to the frequently linked question in question.

Comment: I'm, not sure if I'm confusing something, I see a *Linked* section on the right of a *frequent* question, was this section entitled "Frequent" before?

Comment: @Wolf - No, it wasn't. That section includes questions that were indicated to be duplicates, but not only such questions.

Comment: Anyone know if links from a main site to a meta site count?

Comment: @curiousdannii: I'm guessing only links within the same site count (with Meta being considered a different site from mainsite).