# Frequent question sort excludes the default personalized links?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, sorting, frequent-tab

In [What makes a question appear under 'frequent'?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3473/5764) I describe in more detail what the "frequent question sort order" is all about (in comparison to [What's the 'Frequent' sort function?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172726/168244)). However, it came to my attention that this *excludes* the default personalized links (when clicking on the share button below a post; has the form `http://<base URL>/q/<post>/<user>`). This seems inadequate for those users who follow this path rather than using the default post URL. Am I correct in my assumption? If so, would it be possible to *include* these in the measure (for obvious reasons)?

In more technical terms, the "frequent question sort order" does the following search:

```
url:"http://<base URL>/questions/<post>/*"
```

while personalized links do not have this same format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "frequent question sort order" now launches an updated search query:

```
url:"http://<base URL>/q*/<post>/*"
```

which captures both default and personalized links to the question.